# trying to change text align of botton with effect in xamarin

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, effects

I tried to do that, but I don't understand why it doesn´t change it. Do I have to create a Platform folder for every new cs file created (effects), what do you think can be the cause?. I followed this tutorial https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/effects/creating/
I don't have any errors, but nothing change in my app.

Comment: I check my code and doesn´t give any error or warning, I aready check that the effect is entering. But I think these lines are bad 
    var control = (global::Android.Widget.Button)Control;
    control.TextAlignment = Android.Views.TextAlignment.TextStart;

Comment: Please post your code.